# Cuenta por default al accesar a MySql

Tags: mysql, users-roles

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]Una disculpa, no soy muy conocedor del tema y si me falto especificar algo, con gusto se le hago saber.
Adjunto imagen donde al ingresar a la consola de MySql intenta accesar a una cuenta por default que no es 'root' es un usuario que habia creado al principio por error, y ahora no me puedo deshacer de el. De echo ya le cambie al nombre al original y no coincide con ninguna cuenta de la tabla "mysql.user", pero me sigue apareciendo por default al ingresar a MySql.

De antemano Mucas gracias!

Comment: **[Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en Español](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour)**. lee 
**[cómo crear una buena pregunta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)** y **[¿sobre qué temas puedo preguntar aquí?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)**. **Debes [edit] tu pregunta** con el código que hayas intentado, errores, etc. ¿has investigado al respecto?

Comment: Para conectarte a MySQL tienes que especificar el usuario y contraseña con el cual quieres acceder ejemplo: `mysql -u root -p 1234 -h localhost`

Comment: De acuerdo, asi es como entro con mi cuenta root u otro otras cuentas que ya habia creado, el detalle aqui es, ¿Por que toma una cuenta por default(no especificada o descrita en el -u) MySql al ingresar? Es normal?

Comment: Si específicas usuario el usuario por defecto es el usuario que ejecuta el MySQL en consola.

Comment: Gracias Sergio, y existe alguna forma de quitar/deshanilitar el usuario por defecto de mysql? O de lo contrario, que me recomiendan que haga. Ya que ese usuario por defecto ya no existe porque le cambie el nombre que tenia. Ej: Al inicio se creo el Usuario "X", y con ese entraba por default, despue le cambie el nombre a "Y", y sigue entrando por default con el usuario "X", igual si le pongo la contraseña del usuario "Y" marca error de acceso denegado como la imagen adjunta.